# Delete variable refrence in jni-Android

Tags: android, memory-management, java-native-interface

I have developed a simple live wallpaper application. In that i used a two native functions named captureWallpaper and DrawWallpaper. In that Capture wallpaper function is like below

```
void Java_com_sample_NativeCalls_ captureWallpaper(JNIEnv * env, jobject this){
struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx;
 while(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet)>=0) { 
    if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {      avcodec_decode_video(pCodecCtx, 
               pFrame, 
               &frameFinished, 
               packet.data, 
               packet.size);
      if(frameFinished) {        

    if(img_convert_ctx == NULL) {
        w = pCodecCtx->width;
        h = pCodecCtx->height;
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,  
                                        "video.c",  
                                        "NDK: Cannot initialize the conversion context!" 
                                    ); 
      img_convert_ctx =
         sws_getContext(
               w, h, 
               pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
               textureWidth,textureHeight,textureFormat, 
               SWS_FAST_BILINEAR,
               NULL, NULL, NULL
               );           
      if(img_convert_ctx == NULL) {
        return;
      }

    }         

          sws_scale(img_convert_ctx,
          pFrame->data,
          pFrame->linesize, 
          0, pCodecCtx->height,
          pFrameConverted->data, 
          pFrameConverted->linesize);   

    av_free_packet(&packet);
    return;
      } 
    } 

        av_free_packet(&packet);     
  } 

  av_seek_frame(pFormatCtx,videoStream,0,AVSEEK_FLAG_ANY);
}
```

After that i use those function in my java code in the onDraw function. When invoke this method again and again my ram memory keep increase. I think the reference of any one object was created and not destroyed. Any one aware of this, kindly help me to come out from this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be as simple as:

```
  if(img_convert_ctx == NULL) {
    return;
  }
```

which returns without `av_free_packet`.

However, from the code you show its really not possible to give an answer as it does not show anything about the different variables, pointers or functions.